# Postback for link buttons not working as expected in latest version of chrome(73.0.3683.103)

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, google-chrome, postback

I have an aspx page with 2 linkbuttons:

```
<asp:LinkButton ID="btnSave" runat="server" Text="Save" OnClientClick="javascript: return showTask(false);"></asp:LinkButton>

<asp:LinkButton ID="btnSaveSilent" runat="server" CssClass="invisible" OnClientClick="javascript: return true;"  OnClick="btnSave_Click" ></asp:LinkButton>
```

1 triggering the other via javascript onClientClick and returns true.

```
function showTask(callSaveExit) {         
   if(!callSaveExit) {
      document.getElementById("<%= btnSaveSilent.ClientID %>").click();
   }                    
   return true;
}
```

Both buttons are set up to do postback however, postback on the second button gets lost and btnSave_Click is not triggered in code behind. Only happening on new version of chrome, works fine in IE and firefox and old version of chrome.

It works as expected if I postback on btnSaveSilent instead of btnSave:

```
 function showTask(callSaveExit) {         
   if(!callSaveExit) {
      document.getElementById("<%= btnSaveSilent.ClientID %>").click();
   }                    
   return false;
}
```

So, I do have ways to fix it but I just want to understand why it's not working in chrome when the same code is working in other browsers.